# Angular 2 and SFDC

Tags: javascript, angular

We are going to use Angular 2 to build application in SFDC. I want to know what obstacles we can meet on this way. 
First of all I am interesting:

1. What best practices for deploy angular 2 applications for this time we have?
2. Do we have problems with JavaScript
   Remoting or Remote Objects using them in angular 2?

But I am interesting in all real experience, because information what I find is very poor.

Comment: The topic is really vast, maybe if you can narrow down your question and ask specifics, you might get better support.

Comment: Given that Lightning Components provide a client-side MVC environment natively in Salesforce, perhaps you can add a bit of explanation about why you want to use Angular?

Answer (score 4):

If you're only planning on developing Angular in Visualforce, the task is fairly trivial. If you're trying to implement Angular in Lightning, the task is fairly complex.

## Static Resource

Start by going into Setup, Develop, Static Resources. Upload a ZIP file that contains all the Angular code, or if minified to single file, you can just upload the file directly as a JavaScript resource.

## Visualforce

In Visualforce, simply add this code:

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.angularJS)}" />
```

As in normal Angular, just add `ng-app` to the element where your app resides:

```
<apex:page>
  <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.angularJS)}" />
  <div ng-app="myAppName">
    <!-- more content here -->
  </div>
</apex:page>
```

## Lightning

This is a bit trickier, but not impossible. Read [Using External JavaScript Libraries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_libs_platform.htm) for more info.

Like Visualforce, you need to use an include statement:

```
<ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.angularJS}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.setup}" />
```

As in Visualforce, you need to specify the root `ng-app` element, which can be anywhere in your component. However, unlike Visualforce, all of your AngularJS logic has to be contained inside the controller or helper files, which means your logic will be a bit more complicated.

## Remote Objects

This works as expected with AngularJS; you simply call the appropriate constructor/methods from the "jsShorthand" namespace. If you understand how they work in plain JavaScript, they operate exactly the same in AngularJS. Similarly, JavaScript Remoting works the same as it does with any other JavaScript.

## Notes

It's really hard to give a short, concise answer without a concrete problem to work with. I've personally toyed around with AngularJS in the past, and it works well in Visualforce. For Lightning, I'd skip it and just use Lightning. It's complicated enough on its own without a third-party library.